# Recursive find-replace using sed with URLs

Tags: linux, macos, sed

I have a large set of files in which I need to replace a full URL scheme. Some filenames contain spaces. After much searching and rial and error, this is the closest I've come:

```
find /somedir -type f -print0 -exec sed -i'' -e 's#http\\:\\/\\/domain.com#https\\:\\/\\/www.domain.com#g' {} +
```

The resulting file has the scheme `http:` removed, leaving the `//` - i.e. '//www.domain.com'

Additionally, a NEW file is created, appending `-e` to the filename. - i.e. `some file.php-e` which obviously unwanted.

While this would certainly suffice (after removing the `*-e` files, the OCD in me really wants to know how to do this correctly. Note: I'm working locally on a Mac but will also be performing this on linux.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1**: One way is to use `find` with `xargs`:

```
find /dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's#http://domain.com#https://www.domain.com#g'
```

**Solution 2**: Another one would be to use `find` with `-exec`, very similar as in your question:

```
find /dir -type f -exec sed -i 's#http://domain.com#https://www.domain.com#g' {} +
```

Both solutions will call `sed` with mutiple files as arguments. So `sed` is not called once for every file, but for every set of files.

**Solution 3**: Instead of `sed`, you could also use `perl` for the search-replace-job:

```
perl -i -pe 's#http://domain.com#https://www.domain.com#g' file
```

Combined with the `find`/`xargs` command:

```
find /dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 perl -i -pe 's#http://domain.com#https://www.domain.com#g'
```

Comment: unfortunately the first two error with: `command c expects \ followed by text`. The last one works on a specific file but how do I do it recursively (keeping in mind possible spaces in filenames/dirs)?

Comment: @ChrisChapman Just combine it with the find/xargs command: `find /dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 perl -i -pe 's#http://domain.com#https://www.domain.com#g'`

Comment: Ding Ding Ding! - we have a winner! Thanks a ton. Perl was a jillion times faster too.

Comment: Is it possible to display the files that have changed? Thanks.